# sql server using SUBSTRING with LIKE operator returns no results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created this CTE that returns first and last names from 2 different tables. I would like to use the CTE to identify all of the records that have the same last names and the first name of one column starts with the same first letter of another column.
This is an example of the results of the CTE.  I want the SELECT using the CTE to return only the highlighted results:

[image: Query Results]

```
;WITH CTE AS
            (
            SELECT AD.FirstName AS AD_FirstName, AD.LastName AS AD_LastName, NotInAD.FirstName As NotInAD_FirstName, NotInAD.LastName As NotInAD_LastName 
            FROM PagingToolActiveDirectoryUsers AD JOIN 
                (
                SELECT FirstName, LastName
                FROM #PagingUsersParseName
                EXCEPT
                SELECT D.FirstName, D.LastName
                FROM PagingToolActiveDirectoryUsers D 
                WHERE D.FirstName <> D.LastName AND D.LastName <> D.LoginName
                    AND D.LoginName LIKE '%[0-9]%[0-9]%'        
                ) AS NotInAD ON NotInAD.LastName = AD.LastName
            )
            SELECT *
            FROM CTE
            WHERE (AD_LastName = NotInAD_LastName) AND (AD_FirstName LIKE ('''' + SUBSTRING(NotInAD_FirstName, 1, 1) + '%''')) 
            ORDER BY AD_LastName, AD_FirstName;
```

The result of this query returns no rows.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're enclosing the string to be searched for with single-quotes, but it doesn't appear that the data in `AD_FirstName` has those single-quotes embedded in it. I suggest you replace the first line of the `WHERE` clause with

```
WHERE (AD_LastName = NotInAD_LastName) AND (AD_FirstName LIKE (SUBSTRING(NotInAD_FirstName, 1, 1) + '%'))
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.  I thought that all search strings have to be enclosed in single quotes.  But I was wrong.  Thanks again.

Comment: Only string literals (e.g. 'This is a string literal') need to be enclosed single-quotes. String values which come from a column or which are constructed from values in a column (as in this case) do not need to have single-quotes around them.